# Create activity instead of resuming it

Tags: android

I'm writing a reminder. I use Alarm Manager to call the reminder activity at scheduled times. I want a new instance of the Activity instead of resuming old one because I use setTheme and some other things that must be called before UI initialization.

I copied this code from Android Alarm an Clock:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityReminder.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduled_time, pi);
```

I almost tried all flags to do it with no luck.

I also tried to finish the activity onPause as it's just a reminder with no state, but another problem occurs there:

```
java.lang.runtimeexception wakelock under-locked
```

I think it's because wakelock is released implicitly and the release command raise an exception, but display never turns off this way.

Comment: have you tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK ?

Comment: @Barakat yes, it works. But in manual said don't use it unless you want to have your launcher. And I had doubt if it always works? If you know about this flag please explain it a little.

Comment: You may use fragments and replace them in onResume

Comment: @Barakat once I used fragments, there were really hard to work with, need additional library for old version. I prefer not to use them.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityReminder.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);..using this...??

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK it works.